# Goで2次元配列の部分配列を得たい

Tags: go

Go言語で2次元配列を作成し、そこから部分的に取り出した配列を作りたい時にスライスを用いて下記のように記述しましたが、行は切り出せましたが列は切り出せませんでした。

https://play.golang.org/p/QSzCo8ffBw

つまり上の例では[5,5]を[3,3]になってほしいところが[3,5]になってしまっています。
列も含めスライスするにはどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

残念ながらこのプログラムですと

```
m := [][]float64{
    {1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
}
```

に対して、 `m[0:3][0:3]` は

```
n := m[0:3]
n[0:3]
```

の処理をしたことと同じになってしまいます。行と列が同じ数だとわかりにくいので `n[0:2]` としたものが次のコードです。

https://play.golang.org/p/wUylO3DLyR

期待通りの動作をさせるには行ごとに必要な列を抜き出す処理を書いてあげないといけません。（次のコード参照）

https://play.golang.org/p/0YaZMQiA6o

Comment: スライスのスライスは行を対象としてしかできないということですね。わかりました、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

この場合、`m[0:3][0:3]` は、

```golang
n = m[0:3]
fmt.Println(n[0:3])
```

と同じなので、結果的に行単位でスライスする事になります(`m[0:3][0:3][0:3][0:3]...` の様に何度繰り返しても同じ)。

ですので、例えば以下の様にして部分行と部分列を切り出します。

https://play.golang.org/p/TtFNyNSnCs